# What's a good practice for tracking status code responses so that future, unknown, codes can be visualized on a time series chart?

Tags: time-series, datadog

Say I have an API client, and I track the response codes I get like this:
"some_api_client.#{response.code}" resulting in any number of metrics like: some_api_client.200, some_api_client.400, some_api_client.123456whatever

How can I build a time series chart that is future proof.  That is, I do not want to have to add all potential codes at creation.  I want to add a wildcard.  The best process I have to today is to guess at which codes show up and periodically go into the chart and look for new metrics to add.

That process results in missed codes.  e.g. one day a new code pops up but we don't see/notice it because we hadn't added the metrics.

The answer to this question would explicitly solve for that scenario -- new, unknown, codes would automatically show up in the graph whenever they deem fit to show themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Datadog, splitting the metric name from a tag is a great way to do this.

In your example, the status code is embedded in the metric name, which leads to exactly the problem you're describing - you have to know the metric name ahead of time to add to the dashboard.

Changing the metric emitted to place the response code as a tag will help encompass every possible value, which you can then turn into a cleaner dashboard query.

Example, if this were being emitted from the [Ruby dogstatsd client](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/dogstatsd_metrics_submission/?tab=ruby#count)

```rb
statsd.increment('some_api_client.response', tags: ['response_code:#{response.code}'])
```

Then the Metric Query in the dashboard would look something like this:

```json
...
"q": "sum:some_api_client.response{*} by {response_code}.as_count()",
"type": "bars",
...
```

which would then produce a stacked graph of **all** responses, stacked by the `response_code`. New `response_code` values will automatically be included!

With the recently-released [Wildcard filter](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/wildcard-filter-queries/) feature, you could change the query to scope to a set of specific response codes by group, for example, if you wanted to see all 4xx response codes in a single graph, you could create another graph with a tag scope for only those codes:

```
sum:some_api_client.response{4*} by {response_code}.as_count()
```

Note the `{4*}` scope in the query.